# Adapt image to any device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem I need to put a background image to the body of my page but that this is responsive and suits any size .. this I should do only with css or also javascript, could give an example please

Comment: First hit on Google is [Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Any code you tried to share to show your issue ? did you mind background-size ?

Comment: Sounds like you want a combination of `@media` and `background-size`. You shouldn't need any JS if done properly.

Comment: I tried the code of the tutorial I recommend adeneo, but this does not work from a phone or tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CSS

```
.body {
    background-image: url('myImg.jpeg');
    background-position:center top; // you can change this as you like.
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size:cover; 
    background-size:cover;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Add `-moz-background-size` for Firefox Browser.

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML:

```
<body class="background">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</body>
```

For the CSS:

```
.background {
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Tell me how it goes!